# How to adjust blocks in a 2x2 factorial experiment (Minitab)?

Tags: experiment-design

I'm currently in the planning phase of an experiment involving 2 factors, each with 2 levels, and 3 replications per combination, resulting in 12 experimental runs. In Minitab, the suggested blocks in the factorial design are numbered 1, 2, 3, and 6.
However, practical constraints limit me to conducting only 3 experiments in a block per day. This necessitates extending the blocks to cover three days of experiments, resulting in a total of 4 blocks.
I'm reaching out to the community for guidance on whether manually adjusting the number of blocks from 3 to 4 is statistically acceptable. I want to make sure I'm not overlooking any fundamental concepts in experimental design.
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!